# f2py function release GIL

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, gil, f2py

Does the Global Interpretter Lock (GIL) get released when I call an f2py wrapped function?

(I'm happy to try to discover on my own, but I'm not familiar enough with the numpy source to know where to start looking)...

To clarify, a good answer to this question would *either* help me to know where in the numpy source to look for a `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` *or* it would simply let me know if the GIL is released (preferably with some evidence).

Comment: Which aspect of this question needs to be made more clear? It seems fine to me.

Comment: @Mark -- Yes, I tend to agree :-).

Comment: I agree this is quite clear. Very numpy & f2py specific, but quite clear otherwise. Have you tried asking on http://central.scipy.org ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, f2py defaults to leaving the GIL in place.  However, you can release the GIL by adding the `threadsafe` directive.

example:

```
subroutine foo(a)
!f2py threadsafe
!f2py intent(out) :: a
integer a
a = 5
end subroutine foo
```

Now compile it:

```
f2py -c -m foo --build-dir test_build foo.f90
```

And we can check the source code:

```
grep THREAD test_build/src.*/*.c
build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/testmodule.c:      Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/testmodule.c:      Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

However, if we repeat the process removing the `!f2py threadsafe` line, then the macros to release the GIL aren't included.